# Using Win32::ChangeNotify and waiting for the operation to complete

Tags: windows, perl

Situation: 
I'm watching a folder with Win32::ChangeNotify (don't care about cross-plattform here). 
The folder is shared to the local network. 
A file will be created in this folder from another computer. This process will take some time.

Problem:
The event that something changed is fired while the file is still being written. How can I wait for the write-opertation to finish?

My code looks something like this:

```
my $notify = Win32::ChangeNotify->new($watched_folder, 0, "LAST_WRITE");
if ($notify->wait(5000) == 1) {
    # 1 = The object is signalled
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to do something like store and check the file size in between events and or fire off a different watcher to do this once you detect the new file. After an accepted period where the file size has not changed then you can reasonably expect to open the file.

I've taken this approach with INotify before.