# perl - Monitor Folder and wait till changes been done

Tags: perl

I been trying to create a perl script to monitor the folder for any new sub folders created and have to copy that to a new location.

Till now I was able to come up with the below code. I can able to monitor and caputure the newly created folders but I am not sure of how to wait untill all subfolders/files are created under this newly created folder.

My current code is

```
    use warnings;
use strict;
use Linux::Inotify2;
use File::Copy::Recursive qw(dircopy);

   my $target = "/home/Interface/tmp";

   print STDERR "Watching $target...\n";

  my $in2 = Linux::Inotify2->new();
  die "Inotify2: $!" if (! defined $in2 );

   $in2->watch ($target, IN_CREATE) or die "watch: $!";

#### Need to do Something here to wait untill IN_CREATE EVENT finishes fully#######

   while (1) {
     foreach my $watchdog ($in2->read()) {
          print "$watchdog->{name}\n ";
          caputure_event($watchdog);
      }
   }

sub caputure_event
{
   my ($itemlist) = @_;
   my $itemlistPath = $itemlist->fullname;
   my $itemlistID  = $itemlist->{name};


   copyfile($itemlistPath,$itemlistID);
   $itemlistPath = "";
}  


sub copyfile
{

   my ($sourcedir,$itemlistName) = @_;
   my $targetparentdir = "/home/Interface/Input";
   my $targetdir = "$targetparentdir/$itemlistName";
   dircopy("$sourcedir", "$targetdir");

}
```

My problem is `copyfile` function gets executed before all files are created under the new directory. I would like to get experts ideas to overcome this issue. I could use a `sleep` function but don't think thats much efficient.

Comment: Hi! I asked this question before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21476798/using-win32changenotify-and-waiting-for-the-operation-to-complete it's for Win32, but the solution should work for you, too.

Comment: @capfan Its not a bad idea , but my problem is there is more than one file and number of files vary based on different use cases. I am thinking of something else here... Incase you think of some other idea plz do share it. thx

Comment: You could periodically check for changes of all files inside the folder. It's an expensive operation, but as the OS does (probably) not provide this information, it might be your only chance. Please keep in mind though, that for network copies, it might be the case that the last changed information might not be reliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a below solution and it seems to be working for me.

I been monitoring a folder for any changes (using iNotify2) and tracking it in separately , After a predefined time interval I am using a separate process to do my task for those newly created sub-folders.